# VNC Server not starting on mate arch linux (result = connection refused by computer in vnc viewer) on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, vnc, tightvnc

The log file of tigervnc server has this in it:

```
mate-session[1077]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of DISPLAY=:1 environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
mate-session[1077]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused

(mate-session:1077): dconf-WARNING **: 10:08:58.516: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
mate-session[1077]: WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of SESSION_MANAGER=local/RSG:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1077,unix/RSG:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1077 environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

I tried multiple things like rebooting / editing the /usr/bin/vncserver file, but nothing fixed this (For more check https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1887449#p1887449). Googling for hours also gaved no result.

My xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
mate-session &
```

The problem is with dbus (see the line below) I believe.

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

If I remove that line I get only this error.

```
mate-session[3099]: WARNING: Failed to acquire org.gnome.SessionManager
```

So how could I fix this?